# Numeric Character to date conversion

Tags: r, date

How to convert a character column to date in R
My column is in the format "20110314" (exclude ") where first 4 characters refer to year, next two to month and the last two to date.

Comment: I'm using R, I have a data frame which contains the above mentioned date column as character

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate`: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate

> Date-time data can be frustrating to work with in R. R commands for date-times are generally unintuitive and change depending on the type of date-time object being used. Moreover, the methods we use with date-times must be robust to time zones, leap days, daylight savings times, and other time related quirks, and R lacks these capabilities in some situations. Lubridate makes it easier to do the things R does with date-times and possible to do the things R does not.

**Installation:**

```
# The easiest way to get lubridate is to install the whole tidyverse:
install.packages("tidyverse")

# Alternatively, install just lubridate:
install.packages("lubridate")

# Or the the development version from GitHub:
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/lubridate")
```

**Usage:**

```
ymd(20110314)
#> [1] "2011-03-14"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strptime(as.character(20110314),"%Y%m%d")
[1] "2011-03-14 PDT"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.